# UIScrollview with paging like effect

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, pagination

I have a uiscrollview. Scrollview contains multiple uiview as subview.I want paging like animation effect to scrollview. I have set scrollview.pagingEnabled=NO.

Following is my code

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  {
lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;

}


-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {

    ScrollDirection scrollDirection;
    if (self.lastContentOffset >scrollView.contentOffset.x) {
        scrollDirection = ScrollDirectionRight; } else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.x)  {
        scrollDirection = ScrollDirectionLeft;
         }

    if (scrollDirection==ScrollDirectionRight) {
        CGFloat xOffset = scrollview.contentOffset.x;
        CGFloat yOffset = scrollview.contentOffset.y;

        if (scrollview.contentOffset.x != scrollview.frame.origin.x)
        {


            [scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(xOffset- 320, yOffset) animated:YES];                     


        }

        NSLog(@" ScrollDirectionRight custom  x==%f %f", scrollview.contentOffset.x, scrollview.contentSize.width);


    } else if(scrollDirection==ScrollDirectionLeft) {
        CGFloat xOffset = scrollview.contentOffset.x;
        CGFloat yOffset = scrollview.contentOffset.y;

        if ((scrollview.contentOffset.x != scrollview.frame.origin.x) )
        {
            [scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(xOffset + 320, yOffset) animated:YES];

        }
        NSLog(@"ScrollDirectionLeft custom  x==%f %f", scrollview.contentOffset.x, scrollview.contentSize.width);

           }
    }
```

Through this code im getting paging like effect.but the effect is not smooth.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of animation do you want ?

Comment: whenever i scroll the next view should come in centre

Answer (score 0):

Check out UIScrollViewDelegate method

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
```

In this callback you will modify 'targetContentOffset' to where you like to see scroll offset animation end.

Using it you can make custom pagination implementation a lot smoother.

Comment: please can you tell me in detail